# Get Active QM Instance from Multi Instance Queue Manager and connect

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

I have trouble defining multiple hostname for multi-instance queue manager as I am changing a single instance of queue manager to multi-instance queue manager. 
The existing host is defined in web.config

```
<QueueConfigurationSection>
    <QueueConfiguration>
        <add name="SomeQueueHandler" queueManager="QM1" host="99.99.99.01" port="12345" requestQueue="A.B.REQUEST" service="FLATFILE" responseQueue="B.A.RESPONSE" internalResponseQueue="B.A.INTERNAL" channel="A.SVC.SVRCONN" binding="SOAP11TcpBinding" endPoint="net.tcp://localhost:808/Bus/SomeServiceBus.svc/SOAP11" />
    </QueueConfiguration>
  </QueueConfigurationSection>
```

connection is defined in here

```
public List<QueueHandler> Queues
{
    get
    {
        if (_queues == null)
            _queues = new List<QueueHandler>();
        if (_queues.Count == 0 && _queueConfiguration != null)
        {
            //create queue handlers from configuration provided
            foreach (QueueConfigurationElement element in _queueConfiguration)
            {
                // Using a different connection factory for each queue
                XMSFactoryFactory factory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
                IConnectionFactory connectionProperties = factory.CreateConnectionFactory();
                connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, element.Host);
                connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, element.Port);
                connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, element.Channel); 
                connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
                connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);
                connectionProperties.SetBooleanProperty(XMSC.WMQ_USE_CONNECTION_POOLING, true);

                var queue = new QueueHandler(element.Name, connectionProperties);
                _queues.Add(queue);
            }
        }
        return new List<QueueHandler>(_queues);
    }
}
```

QueueHandler:

```
public QueueHandler(string handlerName, IConnectionFactory mqConnectionFactory)
{
    _connectionProperties = mqConnectionFactory;
    var queueConfigurationSection = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(QueueConfigurationSection.SectionName) as QueueConfigurationSection;
    if (queueConfigurationSection != null)
    {
        if (queueConfigurationSection.QueueConfigurationCollection.Cast<QueueConfigurationElement>().Any(qc => qc.Name == handlerName))
        {
            var element = queueConfigurationSection.QueueConfigurationCollection.Cast<QueueConfigurationElement>().First(qc => qc.Name == handlerName);

            _name = element.Name;
            _serviceType = element.DestinationService;
            _queueManagerName = element.QueueManager;
            _channel = element.Channel;
            _requestQueueName = element.RequestQueue;
            _responseQueueName = element.ResponseQueue;
            _internalResponseQueueName = element.InternalResponseQueue;
            _port = element.Port;
            _host = element.Host;

            //set up binding configuraion
            EndpointType bindingEnum;
            if (System.Enum.TryParse(element.Binding, out bindingEnum))
            {
                _messageType = bindingEnum;

                switch (bindingEnum)
                {
                    case EndpointType.FlatFileTcpBinding:
                        //message received from the request queue is plain text - by configuration
                        _dvsBinding = EndpointHelper.CreateFlatFileTCPBinding();
                        break;
                    // ...
                    default:
                        //unsupported endpoint configuration
                        throw new Exception("Unsupported binding configuration");
                }
            }

            //create endpoint address
            _endPointAddress = new EndpointAddress(element.EndPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

and the hostname and port also defines in the same class in a SendNewMessage method...

```
try
        {
            if (port != 0)
                MQEnvironment.Port = port;
            if (host != ".")
                MQEnvironment.Hostname = host;
            if (channel != ".")
                MQEnvironment.Channel = channel;
            hMgr = new MQQueueManager(manager);
        }
```

So how do I set the standby host in MQEnvironment.Hostname?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to provide MQ with multiple host names and port numbers to connect to.  My suggestions below specify settings similar to how you already specify host and port.

---

For your `QueueHandler` which is using XMS you would replace the properties `XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME` and `XMSC.WMQ_PORT` with the three properties below.  The example below assumes you have defined host1, port1, host2, port2 in your web.config:

```
connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, String.Format("{0}({1}),{2}({3})", element.Host1, element.Port1, element.Host2, element.Port2));
connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
```

Links to the IBM MQ Knowledge center pages for those properties:

- [XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/prx_rtt_conection_name_list.htm)
- [XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/prx_rtt_client_reconect_timeout.htm)
- [XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.msc.doc/prx_rtt_client_reconnect_options.htm)

Under the IBM install directory you can review the following XMS sample program:

```
tools\dotnet\samples\cs\xms\simple\wmq\SimpleClientAutoReconnect\SimpleClientAutoReconnect.cs
```

---

For your `SendNewMessage` method which is written using the IBM MQ C# libraries you would replace your `MQEnvironment` settings with a `Hashtable` of the properties and change the way you call `MQQueueManager` to pass the `Hashtable`.  This has the added benefit of being thread safe where `MQEnvironment` is not. The example below assumes you have defined host1, port1, host2, port2 in your web.config:

```
properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, String.Format("{0}({1}),{2}({3})", host1, port1, host2, port2));
properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
properties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
hMgr = new MQQueueManager(manager, properties);
```

The IBM MQ Knowldege center page "[MQQueueManager .NET class](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q111270_.htm)" has more information on the properties.

Under the IBM install directory you can review the following C# sample program:

```
tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base\SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut\SimpleClientAutoReconnectPut.cs
```

Comment: Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).  If you like it please accept it and/or vote it up.  Glad to be of help.

Comment: Still doesn't work... 
when I used the connection properties to create a connection like this: 
connectionWMQ = cf.CreateConnection(); 
sessionWMQ = connectionWMQ.CreateSession(false,AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
destination = sessionWMQ.CreateQueue(destinationName); 
producer = sessionWMQ.CreateProducer(destination); 

it threw exception: 
... next comment

Comment: XMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however WebSphere MQ reported an error. Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Stack Trace: at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.ProducerShadow.CheckNmqiCallSuccess(String messageid, WmqDestination destination, String probeid, Int32 cc, Int32 rc)

Comment: the producer from "sessionWMQ.CreateProducer(destination)" i can see XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST : hostname1(11111),hostname2(11111). However it also shows "XMSC_WMQ_HOST_NAME : localhost" and "XMSC_WMQ_PORT : 1414". is that what it is trying to connect and threw the exception?

Comment: @Leo Please click edit under your question and add the details.  The comments do not format well so are too hard to read.

Comment: thank JoshMc, newbie here so not familar with the rules. I have created another question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626982/sending-message-to-multi-instance-queue-manager-with-xms