# Sending message to Multi Instance Queue Manager with XMS

Tags: ibm-mq, xms

Following this post: [Get Active QM Instance from Multi Instance Queue Manager and connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964179/get-active-qm-instance-from-multi-instance-queue-manager-and-connect)

I have created a connection

```
XMSFactoryFactory factory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory connectionProperties = factory.CreateConnectionFactory();

connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST, String.Format("{0}({1}),{2}({3})", element.Host1, element.Port1, element.Host2, element.Port2));
connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT, XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT);
connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, element.QueueManager);
connectionProperties.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, element.Channel);
connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
connectionProperties.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_V1);
connectionProperties.SetBooleanProperty(XMSC.WMQ_USE_CONNECTION_POOLING, true);
```

then followed by

```
    try
    {
        using (IConnection connection = _connectionProperties.CreateConnection())
        {
            connection.Start();
            using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(true, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge))
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
                {
                    using (IDestination responseQueue = session.CreateQueue(replyToRequestQueue ? _requestQueueName : _responseQueueName))
                    {
                        using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer(responseQueue))
                        {
                            IMessage response = session.CreateTextMessage(message);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(correlationId))
                            {
                                response.JMSCorrelationID = correlationId;
                            }
                            producer.Send(response);
                            }
                        }
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (XMSException xmse)
        {
            if (xmse.LinkedException != null)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(string.Format(MQTraceMessageFormat,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    TraceMessageType.Error,
                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                    Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "Threadpool " + Name : Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                    null, null,
                    "XMSException.LinkedException on (SendTextMessage) sending message to " + this + 
                    " / xmse.LinkedException.Message : " + xmse.LinkedException.Message +
                    " / xmse.Message : " + xmse.Message +
                    " / xmse.LinkedException.StackTrace: " + xmse.LinkedException.StackTrace,
                    " / xmse.StackTrace: " + xmse.StackTrace,
                    null));
            }
            else
            {
                Trace.TraceError(string.Format(MQTraceMessageFormat,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    TraceMessageType.Error,
                    Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                    Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "Threadpool " + Name : Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                    null, null,
                    "XMSException on (SendTextMessage) sending message to " + this +
                    " / xmse.Message : " + xmse.Message +
                    " / xmse.StackTrace: " + xmse.StackTrace,
                    null));
            }
        }
        catch (MQException mqex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(string.Format(MQTraceMessageFormat,
                DateTime.Now,
                TraceMessageType.Error,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "Threadpool " + Name : Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                null, null,
                "MQException cc on (SendTextMessage) sending message to " + this +
                " Exception: " + mqex.Message +
                " CompletionCode: " + mqex.CompletionCode +
                " ReasonCode: " + mqex.ReasonCode +
                " Stack Trace: " + mqex.StackTrace,
                null));
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(string.Format(MQTraceMessageFormat,
                DateTime.Now,
                TraceMessageType.Error,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "Threadpool " + Name : Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                null, null,
                "IOException ioex on (SendTextMessage) sending message to " + this +
                " Exception: " + ioex.Message +
                " Stack Trace: " + ioex.StackTrace,
                null));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(string.Format(MQTraceMessageFormat,
                DateTime.Now,
                TraceMessageType.Error,
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId,
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread ? "Threadpool " + Name : Thread.CurrentThread.Name,
                null, null,
                "Exception ex on (SendTextMessage) sending message to " + this +
                " Exception: " + ex.Message +
                " Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace,
                null));
        }
    }
```

to send message, however it threw exception at the last line producer.Send(response):

```
renamed.exe Error: 0 : |8/15/2017 10:17:49 AM|Error|25|Threadpool XYZ|||XMSException.LinkedException on (SendTextMessage) sending message to Queue handler ABC:(In ABC.XYZ.REQUEST / Out XYZ.ABC.RESPONSE) / xmse.LinkedException.Message : 2012 / xmse.Message : Failed to send a message to destination XYZ.ABC.RESPONSE.
XMS attempted to perform an MQPUT or MQPUT1; however WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. / xmse.LinkedException.StackTrace: | / xmse.StackTrace:    at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.ProducerShadow.CheckNmqiCallSuccess(String messageid, WmqDestination destination, String probeid, Int32 cc, Int32 rc)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.SpiIdentifiedProducerShadow.SendInternal(MQMessageDescriptor md, Byte[] buffers, Int32 msgLength)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.ProducerShadow.Send(WmqDestination destAtSendCall, WmqMessage message)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ.WmqMessageProducer.Send(ProviderDestination destAtSendCall, ProviderMessage message)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsMessageProducerImpl.SendMessage(IMessage message, XmsDestinationImpl dest)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsMessageProducerImpl.Send_(Boolean inIdentifiedContext, XmsDestinationImpl dest, IMessage message, DeliveryMode deliveryMode, Int32 priority, Int64 timeToLive, Boolean explicitDlvModePriorityAndTimeToLive)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsMessageProducerImpl.Send(IMessage message)
   at DVS.Services.Common.MQHandler.QueueHandler.SendTextMessage(String message, String correlationId, Boolean replyToRequestQueue)
```

From the trace I can see the producer has my two active/standby host in the connection name list, but also "localhost" as host_name and 1414 as port, is that why I cannot connect to it?

```
producer: XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_PUBQ_QMGR : 
XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE_NAME : IBM.XMS.Client.WMQ
XMSC_DISABLE_MSG_ID : False
XMSC_WMQ_RESOLVED_QUEUE_MANAGER_ID : QM1_2017-08-02_15.25.10                   
XMSC_WMQ_CLEANUP_INTERVAL : 3600000
XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_PUBQ : SYSTEM.BROKER.DEFAULT.STREAM
XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_SUBQ : SYSTEM.JMS.ND.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE
XMSC_WMQ_PUB_ACK_INTERVAL : 25
targetClient : 0
XMSC_WMQ_CLEANUP_LEVEL : 1
XMSC_WMQ_MESSAGE_RETENTION : 1
XMSC_WMQ_PORT : 1414
XMSC_WMQ_PROVIDER_VERSION : 7
CCSID : 1208
deliveryMode : 2
XMSC_ADMIN_OBJECT_TYPE : 20
brokerVersion : 0
XMSC_WMQ_USE_CONNECTION_POOLING : True
XMSC_WMQ_TEMP_Q_PREFIX : 
XMSC_ACKNOWLEDGE_MODE : 4
XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_CONTROLQ : SYSTEM.BROKER.CONTROL.QUEUE
failIfQuiesce : 1
XMSC_WMQ_MESSAGE_SELECTION : 0
XMSC_ASYNC_EXCEPTIONS : -1
timeToLive : 0
XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE : 1
XMSC_WMQ_RESOLVED_QUEUE_MANAGER : QM1
XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_NAME_LIST : host1(11111),host2(11111)
XMSC_WMQ_QMGR_CCSID : 819
XMSC_WMQ_SHARE_CONV_ALLOWED : 1
XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_TIMEOUT : 1800
XMSC_WMQ_MAP_NAME_STYLE : True
XMSC_PASSWORD : ********
priority : 4
XMSC_WMQ_LOCAL_ADDRESS : 
XMSC_WMQ_MAX_BUFFER_SIZE : 1000
XMSC_WMQ_CONNECT_OPTIONS : 0
XMSC_DISABLE_MSG_TS : False
XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_QMGR : 
XMSC_WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS : 16777216
version : 7
XMSC_WMQ_CONNECTION_TAG : System.Byte[]
encoding : 546
XMSC_WMQ_POLLING_INTERVAL : 5000
XMSC_WMQ_RESCAN_INTERVAL : 5000
XMSC_WMQ_TEMPORARY_MODEL : SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE
XMSC_WMQ_CHANNEL : MY.SVC.SVRCONN.P
XMSC_CONNECTION_TYPE : 1
XMSC_WMQ_SYNCPOINT_ALL_GETS : False
XMSC_WMQ_HOST_NAME : localhost
XMSC_WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER : QM1
wildcardFormat : 0
XMSC_WMQ_BROKER_DUR_SUBQ : SYSTEM.JMS.D.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE
XMSC_TRANSACTED : True
XMSC_WMQ_MSG_BATCH_SIZE : 10
```

Comment: In the error it says "Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.", I don't see this linked exception, can you capture this?  Look at the sample `SimpleClientAutoReconnect.cs` for how to do this.

Comment: that's all from the exception, nothing else, I also don't know what is the "Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error.", and the code is same from `SimpleClientAutoReconnect`. 
However if I comment out the `XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_OPTIONS` the message can be sent out successfully (using `XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT_Q_MGR` or `XMSC.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT` throws the same exception), but of course the queue manager cannot receive the message when the queue manager is switching to the standby instance.
any clue?

Comment: In the `SimpleClientAutoReconnect` sample it has `if (ex.LinkedException != null) { Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace:\n {0}", ex.LinkedException.StackTrace); }` I don't see this in what you posted, do you have something like that?  What I would expect is a four digit MQRC to go along with the error you have.  Have you tried to test with the original  `SimpleClientAutoReconnect` sample  to see if it works?  If it does not work then it may be a defect and you would open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: I've found the problem, setting transacted to false in `using (ISession session = connection.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge))` will work. Or leave that true and add `session.Commit()` and not using `TransactionScope` also works. So can both XMSC_TRANSACTED and TransactionScope works together?

Comment: You should write up what you found as an answer to your own question.  I think leaving it to true and adding session.Commit is good.  You can do the Commit after you have performed your business logic on the message, in this way if your program crashes before processing the message it will get backed out to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic Client Reconnection with Distributed Transactions are not supported that is the reason you see

```
|XMSException.LinkedException on (SendTextMessage) sending message to Queue handler ABC:(In ABC.XYZ.REQUEST / Out XYZ.ABC.RESPONSE) / xmse.LinkedException.Message : **2012** / xmse.Message : Failed to send a message to destination XYZ.ABC.RESPONSE.
```

2012 is MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR.

Following link talks about it :https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q018380_.htm